# How can I import an other custom component using Vue composition API?

Tags: vue.js, import, components, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to create a Vue 3 component library using composition API:

https://github.com/hyperbotauthor/vue3complib

In one of the components I would like to import an other composition API component ( https://github.com/hyperbotauthor/vue3complib/blob/main/src/components/ChessboardExt.vue ):

```js
import { Perscombo } from "../index"
const PerscomboE = (Perscombo as any).setup

const e = PerscomboE({id: "variant", options: variants}, context)()

const vertContainer = h(
            "div",
            {   
            },
            [e, outerContainer]
        );
```

This almost works, because the component's node is created with its setup function, and it is even rendered on the page correctly, however its `onMounted` function does not get called properly and I get the warning

```
onMounted is called when there is no active component instance to be associated with.
Lifecycle injection APIs can only be used during execution of setup().
If you are using async setup(), make sure to register lifecycle hooks before the first await statement.
```

Not only a warning, but unfortunately I need this for initializing the component, so it is not fully functional without its `onMounted` function as it should be persistent and its state cannot be initialized from `localStorage`.

How do I import an other composition API component into my composition API component's setup properly?

EDIT:

Managed to remove `onMounted` from the child component and I can pass a callback in props for the case when its state changes. So for this case I solved the issue. In general I still don't know the solution.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem in the question. It's good that you have a link, but the question should be perfectly understandable for future readers when it will become unavailable. Consider explaining what you want to achieve. What you did is a hack that should never be done. The only correct way to use a component is to use it in view like a component, i.e. `h(Perscombo...)`.

Comment: Thanks for this insight. For better accessibility I'm thinking about reproducing it in some online playground. I need a dev server running, probably be I can do this with Code Sanbox or similar tool that allows running a server.. I will look into this. EDIT: So I can pass the imported component where I usually pass the HTML tag? EDIT2: But then how to pass event handler callbacks?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea behind render function (and so JSX). There wouldn't be much use from them if only HTML tags were allowed. It's not documented throughly in Vue, but that's how it works. Props are passed as second argument, see https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/render-function.html . In case this was your difficulty, that's it.

Comment: EDIT3: Oh my bad, passing event handlers should be possible using the props as usual. Somehow all examples show HTML tags and I got fixated on them.

Comment: Wait, if I pass `v-on:perscombochanged` in props, then the event handler does not get called. Still don't know how to handle events emitted by imported component.

Comment: See https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/render-function.html#v-on .This doc and this one https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/render-function-api.html have everything you need to know

Comment: Oh, thanks. Even this style of event handling I already used with HTML elements, but the same fixation on HTML prevented me from seeing the same for custom component.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an imported custom component via the `h` function, like an HTML tag. Event handling works the same way as with HTML elements: You prefix the handler name with `on`, use camel case, and pass the handler as a property with this name:

```js
     const variantCombo = h(Perscombo, {id: props.id + "/variant", options: variants, onPerscombochanged: (event:any) => {
         setVariant()
     }})

     const sizeCombo = h(Perscombo, {id: props.id + "/size", options: sizes, onPerscombochanged: (event:any) => {            
         resize(event.value)
     }})

     const upperControls = h(
         "div",
         {   
         },
         [variantCombo, sizeCombo]
     );
```